# How do I print an actual number from this program that contains a function that returns a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *max(int *, int *);

int main()
{
    int *p, i, j;
    p = max(&i, &j);
    
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}

int *max(int *a, int *b)
{
    if(*a > *b)
        return a;
    
    else
        return b;
}
```

This is a program intended to return an integer that is bigger. A function "max" returns a pointer, as you can see. I want to print an actual integer here, but I'm stuck and cannot find a proper way to accomplish it. Can somebody help or give some hint to solve my problem?

**Also**, I would love to know that why there should be an asterisk in front of the function "max". Should there always be an asterisk when a function returns a pointer? The book that I am currently studying lacks information about this specific part, so can someone scratch my back? ;)

Comment: You dereference the pointer as usual?

Comment: You have to initialize `i` and `j` before calling `max`.

Comment: Asterisks in front of the function need not be one when a function returns a pointer. For example, `int **func(void)` will return a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Do we initialize and print i? Isn't it meaningless then to use a max function?

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks, but I meant should there always be an asterisk when returning a pointer. Do you have an answer for this question?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I didn't quite understand you. What do you mean by 'dereference'?

Comment: This kind of code is considered as not so good, but you can have function return a pointer without an asterisk before the function like `typedef int* p_int; p_int func(void);`

Comment: `printf("%d\n", *p);`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thnks! Exactly what I wanted ;) ;)

Comment: As shown by @WilliamPursell and John Bode, dereference the pointer using the dereference operator `*` to get what the pointer is pointing to. You already does that inside the `max` function, have you not written it?

Comment: And if your book lacks information about pointers then it's a rather bad book I would argue. Pointers and their use is such an integral part of programming in C, a decent book should have several chapters about it.

Answer (score 1):

Last question first - `max` returns the value of either `a` or `b`.  Since both `a` and `b` have type `int *` (pointer to `int`), then the return type of `max` also needs to be `int *`.

To access the integer value, you would need to dereference the result of `max`:

```
int main()
{
    int *p, i, j;
    
    /**
     * The values of i and j are indeterminate at this point;
     * you need to assign valid values to them before calling
     * max.
     */
    i = some_value();
    j = some_other_value();

    p = max(&i, &j); 
    
    printf("%d\n", *p);  // Dereference p here to print the int value

    return 0;
}
```

Another way to look at it is that the *expressions* `*a`, `*b`, `*p`, and `*max( &i, &j )` all have type `int`.

If you want `max` to return an `int` rather than an `int *`, then you will need to dereference `a` and `b` in the `return` statements:

```
int max( int *a, int *b )
{
   if ( *a > *b )
     return *a;
   else
     return *b;
}
```

Although...

It's not clear why you're passing pointers as arguments to `max`; you're not attempting to modify the values of `a` or `b`, so there's really no need to use pointers at all.  Just define `max` as

```
int max( int a, int b )
{
  if ( a > b )
    return a;

  return b;
}
```

and call it as

```
int m = max( i, j );
```

or even

```
printf( "max( %d, %d ) = %d\n", i, j, max( i, j ) );
```

Comment: Thanx! What an explanation!